# oscillation of Hamiltonian functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have a (possibly) very stupid question. I don't understand why the supremum is used instead of the maximum. Here's my problem.

We denote by $\mathcal{H}(M,\omega)$ the set of all smooth functions $H : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the following properties.

$\exists$ an open subset $U \subset M$ and a compact set $K \subset M$ such that $U \subset K \subset M \setminus \partial M$ and satisfying

$H_{\big|U} \equiv 0$ is constant.

$H_{\big|M \setminus K} \equiv m(H)$ is constant.

$0 \leq H(x) \leq m(H), \forall x \in M$.

The constant $m(H) := maxH - minH $ is called the oscillation of the function $H$.

Now define the following object, called a capacity.

$c_0 := sup \{ m(H) \mid H \in \mathcal{H}(M,\omega) \}$. Why do we need to use the $sup$ ? Could we not directly use the $max$ ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you easily prove that $c_0$ can be written as some $m(H)$ for some $H$?

Comment: Good question. That's where I am stuck. How could I possibly show that the maximum of the set $\{ m(h) \}$ exists ?

Comment: As long as you can’t prove it can be reached, it is a supremum. Oh, and by considering $\lambda H$ for any $\lambda >0$, you can reach any positive real number.